# How to make changes in Array and Save it

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of subtitles which have start_time, end_time and text i want to make changes in it.

This is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 00:00:01,280
            [end_time] => 00:00:03,109
            [text] => Previously on "Pretty Little Liars..."
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 00:00:03,110
            [end_time] => 00:00:04,780
            [text] => Lesli? What are you doing in Rosewood?
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 00:00:04,790
            [end_time] => 00:00:06,949
            [text] => You mention my name to anyone ever again
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 00:00:06,950
            [end_time] => 00:00:08,219
            [text] => and you'll live to regret it.
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start_time] => 00:00:08,220
            [end_time] => 00:00:09,749
            [text] => (Aria): We went to a junkyard to take some pictures
        )
);
```

I want to change

> start_time in startTime
>
> end_time in endTime
>
> text in data
>
> and you can see this format (00:00:01,280) time in start_time and
>   end_time i want to change this time in milliseconds i have already
>   create a function which convert this time into milliseconds

```
function milliSeconds($time){
                $string = "00:38:42,689";
                $time   = explode(":", $string);

                $hour   = $time[0] * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                $minute = $time[1] * 60 * 1000;

                $second = explode(",", $time[2]);
                $sec    = $second[0] * 1000;
                $milisec= $second[1];

                $result = $hour + $minute + $sec + $milisec;

                return $result;
            }
```

I hope you understand what i want to change in my array after changes i want my array like this

**Result**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [startTime] => 324324324
                [end_time] => 234234234
                [data] => Previously on "Pretty Little Liars..."
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [startTime] => 234234334
                [endTime] => 34234234
                [data] => Lesli? What are you doing in Rosewood?
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [startTime] => 32423423
                [endTime] => 23423423
                [data] => You mention my name to anyone ever again
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [startTime] => 4345345345
                [endTime] => 34234234234
                [data] => and you'll live to regret it.
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [startTime] => 342342343
                [endTime] => 4543534534
                [data] => (Aria): We went to a junkyard to take some pictures
            )
    );
```

I am sorry i have putting wrong milliseconds in startTime and endTime just describe.

I hope i have describe what i want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom function like:

```
function convertKeysToCamelCase($apiResponseArray) {
    $keys = array_map(function ($i) use (&$apiResponseArray) {
    if (is_array($apiResponseArray[$i]))
     $apiResponseArray[$i] = $this->convertKeysToCamelCase($apiResponseArray[$i]);
     $parts = explode('_', $i);
       return array_shift($parts) . implode('', array_map('ucfirst', $parts));
   }, array_keys($apiResponseArray));
   return array_combine($keys, $apiResponseArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this from database, you can make it easier by changing your `SELECT` query, else use below code, where `$input` is the array you shown here and `$result` is your required array, if you want to change current array replace `$result` with `$input`.

Use `array_map()`,

```
$result = array_map(function($v){
            return (object)array(
                    'startTime' => milliSeconds($v->start_time),
                    'end_time' => milliSeconds($v->end_time),
                    'data' => $v->text
                );
        }, $input);
```

Comment: i want to replace one more thing u can see in text there is \" forward slash and double quotes in text i want to replace these with * staerick i have applied str_replace('\"', '*', $v->text) but it not work

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to convert between different subtitle formats. There is easier way to do that https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles

```
$subtitles = Subtitles::convert('subtitles.srt', 'subtitles.vtt');
```

But if you still want to get time as (float):

```
$array = Subtitles::load('subtitles.srt')->getInternalFormat();
print_r($array);
```

It would print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [start] => 137.44
        [end] => 140.375
        [lines] => Array
            (
                [0] => Senator, we're making
                [1] => our final approach into Coruscant.
            )
    )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 140.476
            [end] => 142.501
            [lines] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Very good, Lieutenant.
                )
        )
)
```